# #import without using inheritance between 2 classes

Tags: objective-c

Please help with understanding how #import works without using inheritance.

So I have created a Class named Person and another Class named Body (both classes are inherited from NSObject).

The Body class has 3 ivars  (set with properties)

```
  int hands;
  int feet;
  int legs;
```

I then imported and created an instance of the Body class ( *body) into the Person class. My understanding is that I have now made a 'type' from the Body class. This ivar was then set with properties.

In main, I then created an instance from the Person class named person.
Main recognizes person.body.feet  but I cannot get and set its value directly. The only way it can be done is passing its value into a new int variable and then print out the new variable.

Obviously I’m a struggling newbe but I really want to understand this problem  -

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Person.h"

    int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        Person *person = [[Person alloc]init];

        // this works and NSLog prints out the value is 2
        int feet = person.body.feet = 2;
        NSLog(@"person.body = %i",feet);


        // this does not work - NSLog prints out the value is 0; 
        [person.body setFeet:2];
        NSLog(@"person.body = %i", person.body.feet );



        [person release];
        [pool drain];
        return 0;
    }

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Body.h"

@interface Person : NSObject {

    Body *body;

}

   @property (assign) Body *body;

@end


#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

  @synthesize  body;

@end


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Body : NSObject {

    int hands;
    int feet;
    int legs;

}

@property int hands;
@property int feet;
@property int legs;

@end



#import "Body.h"

@implementation Body

@synthesize hands;
@synthesize feet;
@synthesize legs;


@end
```

Comment: What do you mean "this does not - why ??"?  Error message?  Runtime issue?

Comment: Post your code for the `Body` and `Person` classes, including how these properties are declared.

Comment: @bblum - I do not get error message from [person.body setFeet:2]; but it prints out 'person.body = 0' My question is why does it not print out 'person.body = 2' ?? Thanks

Comment: @AlexWayne - please now see complete code - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you haven't assigned a `Body` object to `person.body` anywhere.

All objects in Objective-C are allocated on the heap.  All those asterisks denote that the variables are pointers, which are mere numbers pointing to memory locations where the objects live.  When you declare a property that holds an object, all you are really doing is creating a place to store a pointer to the object.  You aren't creating the object itself.

So somewhere (most likely in `Person`'s designated initialiser), you'll want to actually create a `Body` object and assign it to the `body` property.

If you *don't* do this, then the memory location will remain at `0`, which is equivalent to `nil`.  When you chain the assignment here:

```
int feet = person.body.feet = 2;
```

...you're assigning `2` to both `feet` and `person.body.feet`, but since `person.body` is `nil`, the setter message to it is ignored.  When later you try to log `person.body.feet`, again, it will be `nil` and return `nil`/`0`.

**Edit:** Having looked at your update, yes, this is your problem.

This line does not create a `Body` object:

```
Body *body;
```

It creates an instance variable for a *pointer to* a `Body` object.

This line does not create a `Body` object:

```
@property (assign) Body *body;
```

It declares a property, which is syntactic sugar for getter and setter method declarations.

This line does not create a `Body` object:

```
@synthesize  body;
```

It synthesises your previously declared property by creating the getter and setter methods.

You need to actually create and initialise a `Body` object and then assign it to your `Person` object's `body` property.  For instance:

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.body = [[Body alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Also, as you aren't using ARC, you should almost certainly declare that property to be `retain` not `assign`, and release it in your `Person`'s `dealloc` method.

Comment: Fantastic answer !! I have but the init method in my Person.m file and all works well. What I was trying to do with this experiment was not to create a actual body object in main and your answer has achieved this brilliantly. Just one point - because the self.body has been allocated memory would it be released when I release the person  object ??

Comment: No, not unless you are using ARC.  Any method with `new`, `alloc`, `retain` or `copy` in the name confers ownership upon you and it's your responsibility to release it.  Use the `dealloc` method for that.  Furthermore, if you declare a property as `retain` or `copy`, the retain count will go up for any object assigned to it.  You should read the [Memory Management guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/) Apple provide for more details.  If possible, switch to using ARC, as it takes a lot of the work off your hands.